# Listbox item's text color change to current Accent color after tap event

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

The problem is illustrated here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPyYIRvYhSI

I don't know what's causing this problem, Same XML was used in a `ScrollView` instead of a `ListBox` without any problems, When I switched to `ListBox`, the problem appeared.

Here's part of the XML (there're actually 114 Grids, I'm only showing now some of them due to the character limitations on posts) :

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox Name="SV1"   FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Grid.Column="1" >
        <Grid Margin="0" Width="416">

            <Grid Name="grid1" Margin="0,0,0,9120" Tap="grid1_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="1"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="1"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid2" Margin="0,80,0,9040" Tap="grid2_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="2"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="2"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid3" Margin="0,160,0,8960" Tap="grid3_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="50"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="3"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid4" Margin="0,240,0,8880" Tap="grid4_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="77"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="4"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid5" Margin="0,320,0,8800" Tap="grid5_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="106"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="5"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid6" Margin="0,400,0,8720" Tap="grid6_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="128"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="6"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid7" Margin="0,480,0,8640" Tap="grid7_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="151"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="7"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid8" Margin="0,560,0,8560" Tap="grid8_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="177"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="8"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid9" Margin="0,640,0,8480" Tap="grid9_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="187"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="9"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid10" Margin="0,720,0,8400" Tap="grid10_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="208"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="10"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid11" Margin="0,800,0,8320" Tap="grid11_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="221"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="11"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid12" Margin="0,880,0,8240" Tap="grid12_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="235"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="12"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid13" Margin="0,960,0,8160" Tap="grid13_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="249"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="13"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid14" Margin="0,1040,0,8080" Tap="grid14_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="255"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="14"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid15" Margin="0,1120,0,8000" Tap="grid15_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="262"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="15"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid16" Margin="0,1200,0,7920" Tap="grid16_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="267"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="16"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid17" Margin="0,1280,0,7840" Tap="grid17_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="282"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="17"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid18" Margin="0,1360,0,7760" Tap="grid18_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="293"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="18"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Name="grid19" Margin="0,1440,0,7680" Tap="grid19_Tap" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="305"  Width="87" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" FontStretch="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="19"  Width="55" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontSize="40" />
                <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,3,55,3" Text="XXX"  Width="324" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have a grid as a single listbox item in listbox. Thus when you tap the listbox the inner grid becomes selected obviously. And selected items in listbox are highlighted by default.